# Choosing the language for the Persistent Menu with facebook messenger bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm currently doing a bot for Facebook messenger.
My bot is multi language but the problem is that I can't find a way to change the language in the bot menu according to the user.

Do you have any idea how to fix that issue?

I can't find any solution: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/persistent-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So facebook response:

> Unfortunately, there is no way to set local for now. This is working
>   as intended but the team will keep your feedback in mind for their
>   next milestones.  Hope this helps.

Comment: A little bump.
I have discovered that you can have many version of a page according to the localisation on facebook. And you can connect many pages to the same bot. So with some tricks you can have a menu different on each page and still keep the same bot

Answer (score 1):

If you're supporting 10 or less languages, one solution could be to at the beginning of each conversation, send a message and have them choose their language using quick replies

EDIT: The persistent menu can't be different for users, so I don't think multi-language is currently supported within the persistent menu.

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2017 (Platform 1.4) this is now supported.

From the Facebook Docs...

> Localization: Developers can now provide text in multiple languages
>   (or entirely different menus) for each local your bot's users may come
>   from.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/persistent-menu