# Persistent menu not showing in Facebook Messenger chat bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

[As I don't know why suggested, using Postman.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45358120/2404470)

[Per docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/persistent-menu/), have succesfully POSTed the configuration to facebook APIs:

[image]

which is not supposed to be anyways [locale specific](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43868085/2404470). Even [I don't see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42643642/2404470)

> Localization: Developers can now provide text in multiple languages (or entirely different menus) for each local your bot's users may come from.

Like [my brother](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712997/lollercoaster), I have [tried almost everything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45002289/2404470) so far

[This looks like some crazy bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/109366693033131/). Is there some work around to add a simplest persistent menu?

Comment: Do you see the update reflected when you send a `GET` on `/messenger_profile`?

Comment: @amuramoto Will surely check and get back! Btw, what do we get if I hit to `/messenger_profile`

Comment: You will also need fields=persistent_menu  Parma. You will get back the stored object that defines your menu. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/#get

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wasted 2 hours on this issue. Until I realised you have to delete the conversation then refresh facebook with ignore cache (ctrl+shift+r in chrome) and then it will show.

Answer (score 1):

The [FB API document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/) states that the API link to hit for applying persistent menu to the page specific bot is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

Notice the **me** after version number i.e `v2.6` in this specific case. However, [this did not worked for a lot of people](https://www.google.com/search?q=persistent%20menu%20fb%20messenger%20not%20showing%20in%20the%20bot)

There is small change in the API link to hit:

**graph.facebook.com/v2.6/[Page ID](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=378910098941520)/messenger_profile?access_token=[PAGE ACCESS TOKEN](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens/#page-access-tokens)**

Notice that **me** is replaced with the fb Page Id.

And the sample payload can still be the same:

```
{
  "get_started": {
    "payload": "Get started"
  },
  "persistent_menu": [
    {
      "locale": "default",
      "composer_input_disabled": false,
      "call_to_actions": [
        {
          "title": "Stop notifications",
          "type": "nested",
          "call_to_actions": [
            {
              "title": "For 1 week",
              "type": "postback",
              "payload": "For_1_week"
            },
            {
              "title": "For 1 month",
              "type": "postback",
              "payload": "For_1_month"
            },
            {
              "title": "For 1 year",
              "type": "postback",
              "payload": "For_1_year"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "title": "fresh jobs",
          "type": "postback",
          "payload": "fresh jobs"
        },
        {
          "title": "More",
          "type": "nested",
          "call_to_actions": [
            {
              "title": "like us",
              "type": "web_url",
              "url": "https://www.facebook.com/nordible/"
            },
            {
              "title": "blog",
              "type": "web_url",
              "url": "http://xameeramir.github.io/"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that it is mandatory to configure `get_started` button before setting up the `persistent_menu`.

Comment: I tried this answer, and solved the problem for messenger phone app. Everything works fine on messenger web, but changes in persistent menu wasn't reflected in the phone app.

Comment: @AhmedShendy The change should reflect for both web and mobile. Not sure how is it possible...

Comment: I think you are right, It works for both web and phone version of messenger, sorry for confusion.